# Learn Ruby on Rails book: email configuration using TextEdit

Tags: learn-ruby-on-rails

I was on page 147 (epub) of Kehoe's [Learn Ruby on Rails](http://learn-rails.com/learn-ruby-on-rails.html) book and copied this code to *config/environments/development.rb*:

```
config.assets.debug = true
   config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port: 587,
    domain: Rails.application.secrets.domain_name,
    authentication: "plain",
    enable_starttls_auto: true,
    user_name: Rails.application.secrets.email_provider_username,
    password: Rails.application.secrets.email_provider_password
  }
```

However, after that and trying to run server I get this:

```
Boruckis-MacBook-Air:learn-rails szymonborucki$ rails s
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 4.1.4 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych.rb:370:in `parse': (<unknown>): could not find expected ':' while scanning a simple key at line 15 column 1 (Psych::SyntaxError)
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych.rb:370:in `parse_stream'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych.rb:318:in `parse'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych.rb:245:in `load'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:325:in `secrets'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/ruby_apps/workspace/learn-rails/config/environments/development.rb:32:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/railtie.rb:210:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/railtie.rb:210:in `configure'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/ruby_apps/workspace/learn-rails/config/environments/development.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:594:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:593:in `each'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:593:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:418:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:427:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:417:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:411:in `call'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:411:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:300:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/ruby_apps/workspace/learn-rails/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/ruby_apps/workspace/learn-rails/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/ruby_apps/workspace/learn-rails/config.ru:in `new'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/ruby_apps/workspace/learn-rails/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:50:in `app'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:130:in `log_to_stdout'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:67:in `start'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/ruby_apps/workspace/learn-rails/bin/rails:8:in `require'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/ruby_apps/workspace/learn-rails/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:27:in `load'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:27:in `call'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client.rb:26:in `run'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/spring-1.1.3/bin/spring:48:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/ruby_apps/workspace/learn-rails/bin/spring:16:in `require'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/ruby_apps/workspace/learn-rails/bin/spring:16:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

I followed the tutorial to the letter, have Ruby 2.1.2 and Rails 4.1.4 installed. What should I do to get through it? I tried using the files from book's GitHub repo but result is the same. Here is the project:

```
https://github.com/SimonBo/learn-rails.git
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stack trace indicates the failure is in line 32 of *config/environments/development.rb*.

Try replacing `domain: Rails.application.secrets.domain_name` with:

```
domain: "example.com",
```

You'll need quotes and a comma.

If you get a subsequent failure on line 36 (as you report), replace:

```
user_name: "my_user_name",
password: "my_password"
```

You've got a problem with the *config/secrets.yml* file not set up properly. If your *config/secrets.yml* file sets the domain value with an environment variable, it's likely your environment variables are not set properly. If you have trouble setting Unix environment variables, you can add credentials directly to the *config/secrets.yml* file. If you do so, you should not check the file into Git until you’ve deleted the secrets from the file.

Comment: Tried it but didn't work, posted terminal printout above

Comment: Thx a lot! Using data directly in secrets.yml solved the problem. I looked at my environment variables and it turns out that TextEdit on Mac may change some of your " into „, that's why it didn't work. You might want to include this detail in your future book update;)

Comment: The book already advises to use SublimeText. You should switch. I will add a warning in the book not to use TextEdit.

Comment: Yeah, Im using Sublime Text, opened the bash file from terminal and it used text edit by default. Well, another lesson learned.

Answer (score 0):

Tried it and got this:

```
$ rails s
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 4.1.4 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/Users/szymonborucki/ruby_apps/workspace/learn-rails/config/environments/development.rb:33:in `block in <top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `example' for #<LearnRails::Application:0x007f9183817380> (NameError)
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/railtie.rb:210:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/railtie.rb:210:in `configure'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/ruby_apps/workspace/learn-rails/config/environments/development.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:594:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:593:in `each'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:593:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:418:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:427:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:417:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:411:in `call'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:411:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:300:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/ruby_apps/workspace/learn-rails/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/ruby_apps/workspace/learn-rails/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/ruby_apps/workspace/learn-rails/config.ru:in `new'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/ruby_apps/workspace/learn-rails/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:50:in `app'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:130:in `log_to_stdout'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:67:in `start'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/ruby_apps/workspace/learn-rails/bin/rails:8:in `require'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/ruby_apps/workspace/learn-rails/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:27:in `load'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:27:in `call'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client.rb:26:in `run'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/spring-1.1.3/bin/spring:48:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/ruby_apps/workspace/learn-rails/bin/spring:16:in `require'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/ruby_apps/workspace/learn-rails/bin/spring:16:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Then it tried example.com with quotes "" ("example.com") and got this

```
rails s
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 4.1.4 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych.rb:370:in `parse': (<unknown>): could not find expected ':' while scanning a simple key at line 15 column 1 (Psych::SyntaxError)
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych.rb:370:in `parse_stream'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych.rb:318:in `parse'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych.rb:245:in `load'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:325:in `secrets'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/ruby_apps/workspace/learn-rails/config/environments/development.rb:36:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/railtie.rb:210:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/railtie.rb:210:in `configure'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/ruby_apps/workspace/learn-rails/config/environments/development.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:594:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:593:in `each'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:593:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:418:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:427:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:417:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:411:in `call'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:411:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:300:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/ruby_apps/workspace/learn-rails/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/ruby_apps/workspace/learn-rails/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/ruby_apps/workspace/learn-rails/config.ru:in `new'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/ruby_apps/workspace/learn-rails/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:50:in `app'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:130:in `log_to_stdout'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:67:in `start'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/ruby_apps/workspace/learn-rails/bin/rails:8:in `require'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/ruby_apps/workspace/learn-rails/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:27:in `load'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:27:in `call'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client.rb:26:in `run'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/spring-1.1.3/bin/spring:48:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@learn-rails/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/ruby_apps/workspace/learn-rails/bin/spring:16:in `require'
    from /Users/szymonborucki/ruby_apps/workspace/learn-rails/bin/spring:16:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Do you think it might be something wrong with my rails/ruby installation on my mac? I tried deleting and reinstalling rails and ruby but alway run into the same problem.

Comment: Hi look domain: "example.com",  I guess you are missing the pattern, it will be good if you can share that code